# Converting MySQL date to Java date

Tags: php, string

Say it I get a date from MySQL table like `2012-03-31`.
I pass this date to a Java application. So Java needs that date as `2012, 02, 31`.

Firstly I explode date, get second element, subtract one from the month value. Then I implode three elements and create new date string.

```
public function convertToJavaDate($mysqlDate) {
    $pieces = explode("-",$mysqlDate);
    return $pieces[0].", ".($pieces[1]-1).", ".$pieces[2];
}
```

Is there a quicker or smarter way to do this ?

Comment: Why not simply get the date from your database formatted that way in the first place?

Comment: how are you getting the date and passing it around? if it's a java app pulling out the date, you should get a native java date object already when you select a mysql date properly.

Comment: @MarcB I pass date to Google ChartAPI.

Comment: @MarkBaker I couldn't understand. Do you mean that, to store dates in database in Java style?

Comment: @trante: so `select date_format(datefield, '%Y, %m, %d') as datestring` instead.

Comment: @MarcB That will give "3" for march. Java needs "2". Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime('2012-03-31');
$javadata = date('Y, m, d', strtotime('-30 days', $date));
```

Comment: What would this give if the date was 31st January 2013?

Answer (score 0):

For java see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.text.ParsePosition)